# use CSS3 not selector to only select elements that are not children of certain element

Tags: css

For example how to change the color of all the `p` that are not belong to the `textarea` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    p {
       color: #000;
    }
    textarea + p {
       color: #222;
    }
    p + textarea {
       color: #222;
    }
```